# Django - if condition always return True

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-rest-framework

I have a condition which call an update function if `is_approved= True`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsStaff])
def update_company_info(request):
    request_qs = CompanyUpdateRequests.objects.filter(id=request.data["request_id"],is_approved=None)
    serializer = CompanyUpdateRequestSerializer(request_qs[0], data=request.data, partial=True)
    approved = request.data['is_approved']
    if serializer.is_valid():
        if approved:
            print(request.data['is_approved'])
            update_info(request_qs[0].company, request_qs[0])
        serializer.save()
```

No matter the boolean value the `if approved:` gets executed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: check type of approved

Comment: Writing like that, only  False and None will not execute the code. Like @sahasrara62 you have to check your type or change the condition to match with your use case.

Comment: You are right. I is_approved was a string. I converted it to bool and it worked. If you add an answer I will  select it as right answer

Comment: I am assuming you send the data as JSON? You can send the value as a proper boolean instead of a string then: `{"is_approved": true}`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that's right